# select non-na value in similar columns in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have 3 pairs for countrycode, statename, statecode,and I'd like to extract the non-NaN values:

```
 countrycode_x statename_x statecode_x countrycode_y statename_y statecode_y
          NaN         NaN         NaN           NaN         NaN         NaN
           US      KANSAS          KS           NaN         NaN         NaN
           CA     ONTARIO          ON           NaN         NaN         NaN
           US       TEXAS          TX           NaN         NaN         NaN
          NaN         NaN         NaN           NaN         NaN         NaN
          NaN         NaN         NaN           NaN         NaN         NaN
          NaN         NaN         NaN            CA     ALBERTA          AB
           US       TEXAS          TX           NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Expected outcome:

```
countrycode    statename   statecode 
          NaN         NaN         NaN                   
           US      KANSAS          KS                 
           CA     ONTARIO          ON                 
           US       TEXAS          TX                  
          NaN         NaN         NaN                  
          NaN         NaN         NaN                   
          CA        ALBERTA       AB        
          US        TEXAS          TX
```

Comment: And you want to keep the rows with all `NaN`s?

Comment: yes. there are more columns in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby` over the columns axis, using the value before the `'_'` character in the column label for the grouper, then pick the `first` value for each to reconcile the `NaNs`

```
df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('_').str[0], axis=1).first()
```

---

```
  countrycode statecode statename
0        None      None      None
1          US        KS    KANSAS
2          CA        ON   ONTARIO
3          US        TX     TEXAS
4        None      None      None
5        None      None      None
6          CA        AB   ALBERTA
7          US        TX     TEXAS
```